# PHP - need help in php form element (Header part)

Tags: php

I am a beginner in php.
I am trying php to send mail.
My mail goes to mail client but it does not show the header part well as I wanted.
I am using the following codes ----

```
<?php
  //validation expected data exists
  if(!isset($_POST["name"]) ||
     !isset($_POST["city"]) ||
     !isset($_POST["email"]) ||
     !isset($_POST["phone"]) ||
     !isset($_POST["message"])) {
     died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
  }
  //Subject
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $subject = "NO REPLY";
  $email = $_POST["city"];
  $phone = $_POST["email"];
  $website = $_POST["phone"];
  $message = $_POST["message"];
  $header = "from: $name <$email>";
  $to = 'info@mishmihillsadventure.in';
  $send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
  //Check, if message sent to your email
  // Display message "We've recived your information"
  if($send_contact){
  echo "We've received your contact information";
  }
  else{
  echo "ERROR";
  }
?>
```

Comment: I m not a fan of shoving libraries down people's throats but the php mail function is a mess give [php mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) a look.

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: I have correct some of my mistakes in the header part but still its not showing the Phone number in the header part.

I used the following now but still its not showing the Phone numbers in the header part....

I used this codes now...
 

     $name = $_POST["name"];

      $subject = "NO REPLY";

      $city = $_POST["city"];

      $email = $_POST["email"];

      $phone = $_POST["phone"];

      $message = $_POST["message"];

      $header = 'From: ' . $name . '<'  . $email . '>' . "\r\n";

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = $_POST["city"];
$phone = $_POST["email"];
```

Is this really what you want? Shouldn't it be:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
```

And try the following headers:

```
$header = 'From: ' . $name . '<'  . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: I used the following now but still its not showing the Phone numbers in the header part....

I used this codes now...
 

     $name = $_POST["name"];
      $subject = "NO REPLY";
      $city = $_POST["city"];
      $email = $_POST["email"];
      $phone = $_POST["phone"];
      $message = $_POST["message"];
      $header = 'From: ' . $name . '<'  . $email . '>' . "\r\n";

Comment: You want the phone number to appear in the headers part? Where? You set a variable `$phone`, but you never use it. Perhaps you want to append it to the message like this? `$message = "Phone: $phone\r\n\r\n" . $_POST["message"];`

Answer (score 0):

Use (atmost) following headers while sending mail via PHP -

```
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$header .= "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

//If want to `CC` someone add
$header .= 'Cc: abc@email.com' . "\r\n";
```

Using variables in `Double quotes` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like in code mentioned below,

```
<?php
$to      = 'test@to.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: test@from.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: test@from.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'Msg send..';
} else {
    echo 'Msg Not send..';
}
?>
```